# Aginity Pro not opening

Tags: aginity

I'm triing to open Aginity Pro but it doesn't, it remains on background.

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve that problem?

Many thanks!

Xevi

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
start wmic serwis
```